# Catalyst Chained routing "loop"

Tags: perl, catalyst, chained

i've got a problem that i wasn't able to solve yet, and hope you can help :)

i have build a CataPLACK-Application with a web-interface. Now i am supposed to establish a JSON/REST/XML-Api, so i thought i could do something like this:

```
/ => root
/blog/ => ... 
/news/ => ...
/api =>chainedTo(root) PathPart(api) Args(1) { set_view($arg) };
```

how do i loop back api to root (/), so i can redispatch the whole request with a different view without having to establish a lot of "fake routines" ?

i feel there must be a clean way ...

Comment: Andreas, set your profile info I you like us to know you name.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the differences between `$c->forward` / `$c->detach` and `$c->visit` / `$c->go` in the manual. I think you'll find you can probably build a `$c->go()` construct from within your api method that achieves what you're after.

It's still a bit messy though, particularly if you have to de-reference the URI back to an action manually.

You can achieve the same effect with a lot less hassle by adding the 'api' path-part at the end rather than the beginning, so it just becomes an argument to the request that you can test for in your `auto` sub, and set whatever stash variables you need. Then you don't need to do any re-dispatching. Only you can decide whether such a URI scheme will be clean enough and appropriate for your application.